# Origin of "embarrassingly parallel" phrase

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce

For the purposes of history on wikipedia, is anyone familiar with the origin of the phrase "embarrassingly parallel". I've always thought that it may have been coined by a random Google employee who first worked on map-reduce. Does anyone have any concrete info on the origin?

Comment: Does it even *have* a history?

Comment: My major prof used it a lot, way before MapReduce/Google.

Comment: I've always called that "dumb parallel".

Comment: It’s older than you think. Google timeline search: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&tbs=tl:1&q=%22embarrassingly+parallel%22&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=

Comment: Good call on the google timeline search. It's much older than I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first use I could find in an advanced Google book search was from an [IEEE Computer Society digest](http://books.google.com/books?id=VPZVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22embarrassingly+parallel%22) published in 1978. The context and the fact that the author had "embarrassingly" in quotes indicates to me that the phrase was not coined here, but had been used before this.

Answer (score 1):

It's decades old, but I first heard it used in reference to graphics rendering. Imagine you're rendering an animated movie: each frame is 2000x1000 pixels, there are 24 frames per second, 60 seconds in a minute, and 100 minutes in the movie. That's almost 300 billion pixels that can all be computed in parallel. That's so parallel that it's embarassing to compute it serially.

Comment: No, I think it refers to graphics hardware, where they get speed by no amazing feat, but by simply using more silicon and transistors to do more work in parallel. "WOW! How'd you get it to render so fast..?" "Uh, nothing special, I just used [2.15B](http://www.guru3d.com/article/radeon-hd-5850-review-crossfire/2) transistors on the chip. Everything's parallel." "Embarrassingly parallel!"

Answer (score 0):

Try this search : http://www.google.co.nz/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enNZ364NZ365&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=etymology+embarrassingly+parallel